# Cannot boot from grub / initramfs to desktop in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub, initramfs, kernel-panic

Recently I had to download some files for my uni coursework on Docker. I think they were temporarily installed on /var/ and I had to create some syslinks to enable me to have the space to install it. I haven't turned off my computer since, until around 3 hours ago.

The system froze whilst I was on a browser so rather than just pulling the plug I decided to try to safely turn it off as everything but mouse movement and ctrl-alt-f1 worked (even the system clock froze). I entered `reboot` and the system promptly turned off. Then the screen started flashing while failing to reboot and would not stop so I had to reboot with the power. I managed to get into grub and eventually found vmlinuz files but I have a few questions:

1. Should I be running in the format of `hd(2,6)` or `hd(2,gpt6)`? When entering `ls` I get `(hd0,1),(hd2),(hd2,gpt1),....(hd2,gpt6)` and I am unsure of how I should call it in setting the root
2. Should I be running vmlinuz and initrd.img or the ones with version numbers, such as `vmlinuz-5.4...`?

So far I have tried all combinations and nothing works, however when I run the latest version vmlinuz and initrd.img files and enter `boot`, it takes me to initramfs and I have tried a few things. It says failed to find root in etc/fstab. Running `exit` makes the kernel panic and it freezes, forcing me to reboot, and boot causes it to panic and freeze too.

[edit] image of error https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7BWs.jpg

I have no idea how to get back into linux and no idea what caused it - any help would be greatly appreciated. The only thing I can think of is a fresh install but I think that would wipe my hard disk and I would lose my files. Thank you

Comment: `(hd2,gpt6)` should be the most precise one, but anything that will give you files when running `ls` should work. I'm not sure how mint names the images, but `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img` may be a symlink to the most recent versions. You'll want to add `root=` to your [`cmdline`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters) to tell the `initrd` where your root partition is located. The safest way to specify `root` may be `PARTUUID=`, but you can also use e.g. `root=/dev/sda2` (substitute with the correct parttion).

Comment: If you pick the images with the version numbers, make sure they match for kernel and initrd (and start with the highest).

Comment: thanks for your help @rudib , just to clarify with the root= command, should I run that like `initrd hd(2,gpt6)/initrd..... root=/dev/sda2` or is that in the initramfs? Will read the link too, thanks again

Comment: you add it in the `linux` line (which should come first). `vmlinuz` -> kernel, `initrd` -> initramfs!!

Comment: example: `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.8 root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff`

Comment: @rudib I tried it and it booted to initramfs but I think it's the same problem, I changed my post to show the error as best as I can

Comment: can you find (the contents of) your root with grub's `ls`?

Comment: So I have just noticed that my root is in gpt2 while the most up to date vmlinuz and initrd are in gpt6. Inside root is just Desktop, and inside that it is blank @rudib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116522/discussion-between-samuelf80-and-rudib).

Comment: @rudib is using kernel options and using set root is the same?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo No, `set root=` in grub tells grub where to look for the `kernel` and `initramfs` (so basically the root of the boot partition). And the kernel option `root=` tells the initamfs/kernel where the 'os' root partition aka `/` is located also see [kernel parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kernel_parameters).

Comment: @rudib did you mind take a look on my [q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648824/stuck-at-busy-box-attempt-to-boot-old-linux-at-another-partition)?
Samuelf80 do you able to normally boot now?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo no, had to clean reinstall. Managed to recover my files using my main windows operating system, so at some point have to remove the old version of linux from my hard drive.

Comment: Also @rudib, I didn't thank you before but thanks for all of the help that time ! Unfortunately couldn't get it to work but thanks for working through that with me, I used elements of that method since actually !